# How to get only some of the elements of an object using only for-in and if-else

Tags: javascript

For example, if we have the following object in javascript:

```
var person,
    property;
    
    person = {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName:"Doe",
        age: 50,
        eyeColor: "blue",
        hairColor: "black",
        profession: "doctor"
    }
```

How do I print out only the second and fourth property of this object with for-in and if-else?

Comment: You may have a look of [Does JavaScript guarantee object property order?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5525795/14032355) before asking this question.

Comment: is it a school exercise?

Comment: There's no guarantee that those properties will be in that order so talking about "second" and "fourth" is not really useful. Are there specific properties you need to access?

Comment: console.log(person.lastName), console.log(person.eyeColor) - you should not try to access object properties by their numerical index.

Answer (score -2):

another way would be.

```js
var person = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: 50,
    eyeColor: "blue",
    hairColor: "black",
    profession: "doctor"
  }
  
  for(key in person){
    var index = Object.keys(person).indexOf(key);
    if(index === 1 || index === 3){
      console.log("Key:", key, ", Value:", person[key]);
    }
  }
```